# Mysql Tree structure counting all children who are active

Tags: mysql, tree, children

I have a structure like this:

Tree:
id,parent_id, lft, rght, user_id

Users:
id, username, active

What I am trying to do is a single query (perhaps with subqueries??) that will return me the child count for every top node in the tree WHERE, in the user table, active is set to 1. Any idea how I could go about this?

Comment: If you can have any number of levels in your tree, that's gonna be difficult. If you know that you have at most *n* levels (with n quite small), you can do that in a query that performs at most *n*-1 self joins on the `Tree` table.

Answer (score 0):

Since you obviously can have 'unlimited' count of levels, such single command is impossible. But you can

1) Do the counting in your program (be it php, java, whatever) through a recursive algorithm with multiple SQL calls. <-- Do it this way if you can.

2) Add field 'cached_active_count' to Tree table and update it using triggers on every insert, update and delete query. This option is most difficult to set up as it requires several triggers and is very prone to errors, but if you want efficiency, this one reads the result fastest.

3) Make SQL recursive function... but MySQL doesn't like recursion, thus you would need fake recursion using a loop and queue made of temporary table, which would not be simple easy code again.

4) Make SQL function that will in loop run query over whole table, looking for bottom-most not calculated nodes and calculating them layer by layer. This solution is probably the easiest*, but also least efficient one. *(easiest != easy)

5) However, if you except "unlimited" depth in fact limited, let's say of max N levels deep, you can make "UGLY" sql select query consisting of N table joins...